# Infinispan how to select an embedded entity

Tags: full-text-search, hibernate-search, infinispan, redhat-datagrid

I am using RedHat DataGrid (it is like Infinispan).
I have this class Execution which has a collection of `Workflow` type. I need to execute the following query:

`select e.workflow from Execution e where e.workflo.id in (1, 2)`

It is possible? I tried but I have an error: "the workflow type is an embedded entity".

```
    @ProtoDoc("@Indexed")
    public class Execution {
        
        @ProtoDoc("@Field(index = Index.YES, store = Store.NO, analyze = Analyze.NO)")
        @ProtoField(number = 1, required = true)
        String fileName;
        
        @ProtoField(number = 2, collectionImplementation = ArrayList.class)
        List<Workflow> workflow = new ArrayList<>(0);
        
        public Execution () {}
    
        @ProtoFactory
        public Execution (String fileName, List<Workflow> workflow) {
            this.fileName = fileName;
            this.workflow = workflow;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With embedded queries you need to use the fully qualified name of the target Java class.